# AWS Cognito - Sharing logged in user information between app clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, idp

I have below requirements;

- Keep a single user pool for different apps.
- There'll be an app client that signs in users.
- Other apps should be able to receive ID or access token (whatever possible) after "**Main**" app client's sign in flow.
- But each app client has its own read/write rights on user fields, so I can't share "**Main**" app client's ID token to other app clients.
- Each app client can use a different web browser to access this within a mobile app.

Based on above, is there a way to receive ID token once for a "**Main**" app client and retrieve it differently per app client without forcing user to login again?

Thanks in advance!